# How to appear an image into an imageview with an animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, imageview

i have a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/who" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"/>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Presents"
        android:textColor="@color/color1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.6" 
        />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the activity:

```
package com.n;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyMainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    }
}
```

What i want is, after X seconds, to show another image over the last imageview with a zoom transition animation. is possible? tnx!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with scale animation

it should be something like this (I'm not 100% sure of the values of the scale animtion, but u can play with it)

```
private static final int DURATION = "put here duration...";
private static final int OFFSET = "put here offset...";


ScaleAnimation zoomAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.1f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 1.0f, 0.5f,0.5f);
zoomAnimation.setDuration(DURATION);
zoomAnimation.setStartOffset(OFFSET); 
newImageView.startAnimation(zoomAnimation);
```